# Blazor: how to submit the form with single click on a button

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

```cs
<EditForm autocomplete="off" class="contex card-body" Model="Input" OnValidSubmit="OnSaveChangesAsync">
  <!-- all fields and validations -->
  <EditButton>Save changes</EditButton> 
</EditForm>
```

I have a form like this. It performs many validations. Then the changes are saved. ALMOST everything works.

The problem is the first click on the button does nothing (seems like making the button active), the second click actually submits the form. Of course it's probably focus on a form element, but this should not prevent the button from working normally.

How to make the button work on fist click, instead of double-click / second click?

EDIT: Edit button source:

EditButton.razor:

```cs
@namespace Woof.Blazor.Components
<button type="submit" class="@CssClass" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">@ChildContent</button>
```

EditButton.razor.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Woof.Blazor.Components {

    public partial class EditButton {

        [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a collection of additional attributes that will be applied to the created element.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        string CssClass {
            get {
                const string defaultClass = "btn btn-primary baseline";
                if (AdditionalAttributes != null &&
                    AdditionalAttributes.TryGetValue("class", out var @class) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(@class, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))) {
                    return $"{defaultClass} {@class} ";
                } else return defaultClass;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Let me rephrase the question to make it clearer: I suspect the first click on the button just gives the button focus (takes the focus out of an input element), the second click is registered as a "submit" action. I want to skip the focussing part and make the first click to call `OnValidSubmit` `EventCallback`. It's also important it worked that way on tablets when the button is touched. One touch should save changes. The consequences of accidentally clicking the button are next to none. If no changes are made to the form, my code will skip the update. If invalid changes are made - the validation won't allow `OnValidSubmit` to be triggered. When valid changes are made, but not all of them are entered - the user can still re-edit the saved item. From the other hand - if the user forgets to save the changes - this would lead to possible mistake in the form to stay instead of being corrected, without user even knowing what happened. The user can close the browser, the tablet device can lock the screen. A couple of times I personally made similar mistake using a banking application: I thought I sent the money transfer and waited for delivery, only to find out I haven't confirmed the transfer and the store is still waiting for my payment. I'd call it a major annoyance, I don't like it when it happens to me, so I don't like it to happen to the users of my application.

Comment: Where do you get `EditButton` from? What is it? Please show that component

Comment: @Vencovsky: Here, I added the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of this answer is to refute the validity of the accepted answer by the author
of the question himself.

Here's the code from the question as posted by the OP...

### EditButton.razor

```
@namespace Woof.Blazor.Components
<button type="submit" class="@CssClass" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">@ChildContent</button>
```

### EditButton.razor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Woof.Blazor.Components
{

    public partial class EditButton
    {

        [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a collection of additional attributes that will be applied to the created element.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        string CssClass
        {
            get
            {
                const string defaultClass = "btn btn-primary baseline";
                if (AdditionalAttributes != null &&
                    AdditionalAttributes.TryGetValue("class", out var @class) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(@class, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    return $"{defaultClass} {@class} ";
                }
                else return defaultClass;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The following is my code for testing's purposes. Copy it into the Index page and run the app... Note that I'm using Blazor Server App.

```
@page "/"

    @using System
    @using System.Collections.Generic
    @using System.Linq
    @using System.Threading.Tasks
    @using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
    @using Woof.Blazor.Components


    <EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" 
                                OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
   
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <InputText autocomplete="off" Id="name" Class="form-control" 
                                 @bind-Value="@Model.Name"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Name)" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Text: </label>
            <InputTextArea autocomplete="off" Id="body" Class="form-control" 
                                  @bind-Value="@Model.Text"></InputTextArea>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Text)" />
        </div>
        <EditButton>Save changes</EditButton>

    </EditForm>

    @code
    {
        private Comment Model = new Comment();

        protected void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Handle valid submit");
        }

        protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handle Invalid Submit");
        }

        public class Comment
        {
            [Required]
            [MaxLength(10)]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Text { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

### TEST 1

1. Type a name in the Name field, and then tab to the Text field.
2. Enter some text, But DO NOT PRESS THE TAB KEY: Leave the input focus in the Text field.
3. With the mouse pointer click on the "Save changes" button, and then go to the Output window
4. As you can see, the click on the button has submitted the form, and printed the text: "Handle valid submit"

This indicates that your assertion

> Then the issue: if another edit component has focus, the button first must get focus, then it can be clicked

is not only false, but is clearly revealing how you 'choose' to ignore how UI elements in the Web and elsewhere behave.

### TEST 2

1. Type a name in the Name field, and then with the mouse pointer click on the "Save changes" button. DataAnnotations validation immediately responds with the message: "The Text field is required."
2. Go to the Output window, and see the message: "Handle Invalid Submit"
3. Return to the Web page, and enter some text into the Text Field, and then
   with the mouse pointer click on the "Save changes" button.
4. The red text message disappears.
5. Now go to the output window, and see that no message was issued, which
   especially means that the click event has never been fired. This has lead you
   to form the false assertion that "the click is not seen as click by the
   browser itself." But, alas, there has never been a click on the "Save
   changes" button. Your explanation is meaningless, and provide no value to
   explain what is going on here...

   When you direct the mouse pointer towards the "Save changes" button and
   attempt to click it, the Text field lose focus, the result of which
   is DataAnnotations code removes the red message, and the ensuing re-rendering
   of the components involved. This is done in such a speed that you cannot
   produce a click that will execute before the re-rendering. This code is
   executed in the speed of light, but even if you were quick enough (speed of
   light, right) to insert a click in the interval between loosing the focus to
   initiating a re-rendering, the code is performed in a given order. In any
   case, the fact remains that the components are re-rendered, and you did not
   succeed in eliciting or issuing a click event because the "Save changes"
   button did not have a focus. As I've shown in Test 1, no focus is needed. It
   has always been like that, from the very beginning :)

### TEST 3

1. Type a name in the Name field, and then with the mouse pointer click on the "Save changes" button. DataAnnotations validation immediately responds with the message: "The Text field is required."
2. Go to the Output window, and see the message: "Handle Invalid Submit"
3. Return to the Web page, and enter some text into the Text Field, and then
   with the mouse pointer move the focus to the Name field.

As you can see, the red message has been removed, that is to say, re-rendering
of the component has taken place.
4. Now, while the focus is in the Name field, with the mouse pointer click on
the "Save changes" button.
5. Go to the Output window, and see the message: "Handle valid submit"

### TEST 4

1. Add the following onmouseover="document.getElementById('name').focus();" to the button
   element in the EditButton.razor file. This comes instead of onmouseover="this.focus()"
   used in the accepted answer as the solution.
2. Type a name in the Name field, and then with the mouse pointer click on the "Save changes" button. DataAnnotations validation immediately responds with the message: "The Text field is required."
3. Go to the Output window, and see the message: "Handle Invalid Submit"
4. Return to the Web page, and enter some text into the Text Field. Now,
   as you move the mouse in the direction of the "Save changes" button,
   the mouseover event is triggered, and the focus is set to the Name field.
5. Now, while the focus is in the Name field, with the mouse pointer click on
   the "Save changes" button.
6. Go to the Output window, and see the message: "Handle valid submit"
7. Note that the behvior elicit by swaping onmouseover="this.focus()" with
   onmouseover="document.getElementById('name').focus();" is identical
   Clearly, you don't have to set the focus of the "Save changes" button in
   order to issue a single click. A single click is possible only after the
   component is refreshed by the code related DataAnnotations.

Wrapping up: Whatever you've said in your answer as well as comments are baseless,
wrong and misleading. The only assertion I agree with is that it was an easy question:
"You made at least 2 mistakes. First: you mistook this for an easy question"

Yes, it was an easy question, and I've provided an answer, given the details you provided,
that is correct, and that cannot even be invalidated by the current answer.

Please, remove your answer, as it is misleading and wrong. It certainly shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to get back here for a long time - of course you're right. I double checked that. What's more - you have helped me to fix some serious issues with my code elsewhere (also a couple of months ago). The unexpected results I got was related to some ugly hacks I used to solve one problem, creating a couple of other problems. I accepted your answer as the correct one. I removed the ugly hacks and the buttons work as intended.

Comment: Thank you... I've forgotten this answer altogether.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the first click on the button does nothing

What do you expect it to do ? Do you have code that you expected to execute, and it did not.

> submits the form

The form is never submitted. This is an SPA App, you can't submit or to be more precise, you should not submit your form data. Where do you submit your data form to. Please, put the following code in the OnSaveChangesAsync method, click only once on the button, and view the result in the Output window:

```
 private void OnSaveChangesAsync()
 {
    Console.WriteLine(Input.<Type a property name defined in the Input 
                      object>);
 }
```

If the value of the given property is printed in the Output window, then all is right. If not, please, post all your code, as well as reference to the custom EditButton.

Comment: You made at least 2 mistakes. First: you mistook this for an easy question. Then: missed the part when `OnValidSubmit` is set. It IS set, so this implies, something is called when the submit button is clicked. And it indeed is. The problem is, when the button has no focus, first click gives a focus to it, the second actually calls `OnValidSubmit`. This isn't used to eject the user's seat, so it does not need a "click confirmation". I asked how to get rid the focusing part. Just make submit work immediately.

Comment: Your assumption that the first click on the submit button gives a focus to it only, without initiating and performing the code in the pipeline is baseless and naive. No matter where is the input focus, once you click on the submit button the code in the pipeline is executed, ending in a call to OnValidSubmit method, if your data is valid, otherwise displaying error messages. This is how the web works. I could only guess from my own experience what could be the source of the problem. If you really want to solve your problem, please upload a complete repo of your app, and I'll try to solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the full app is a huge hog, hundreds of thousands LOC, "no can't do". I don't assume the code like in validations is not executed, I just omitted it for brevity and clarity. If the form is valid (if it wouldn't - the `OnValidSubmit` would not be triggered at all) - the validation shouldn't stand in the way, should it? Do you suspect a property of the model is not set despite it's visible in the form? So when I click the button - then the binding takes effect? It's possible! I'll check that out and let you know tomorrow.

Comment: As promised, I checked some things. First I added `@onclick` event handler just to see what happens. If it's a binding issue - the click handler will be called, but the submit event won't go. But the click handler was not called either. That rules out the data binding issues. It's just the default browser behavior. In the answer below I described how to change this behavior. BTW, my description of the problem was not clear enough - my fault. I was too tired, you know, deadline and working over time ;)